# How to implement a close button for a TTabsheet of a TPageControl

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

How can I implement a close button for a TTabsheet of a TPageControl like Firefox?

**Edit:**
Delphi Version: Delphi 2010
OS: Windows XP and up

Comment: What style do you mean? The one where each tab has its own button, or the style where there's one button at the far right that applies to whichever tab is currently active?

Comment: @Rob Yes, with a close button on each tab

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Now with Theme support (include `Windows, UxTheme, Themes` units)!

```
type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    {...}
  private
    FCloseButtonsRect: array of TRect;
    FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex: Integer;
    FCloseButtonShowPushed: Boolean;
    {...}
  end;

{...}

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  PageControlCloseButton.TabWidth := 150;
  PageControlCloseButton.OwnerDraw := True;

  //should be done on every change of the page count
  SetLength(FCloseButtonsRect, PageControlCloseButton.PageCount);
  FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := -1;

  for I := 0 to Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1 do
  begin
    FCloseButtonsRect[I] := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  CloseBtnSize: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabCaption: TPoint;
  CloseBtnRect: TRect;
  CloseBtnDrawState: Cardinal;
  CloseBtnDrawDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  PageControl := Control as TPageControl;

  if InRange(TabIndex, 0, Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1) then
  begin
    CloseBtnSize := 14;
    TabCaption.Y := Rect.Top + 3;

    if Active then
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 4;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 6;
    end
    else
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 3;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 3;
    end;

    CloseBtnRect.Bottom := CloseBtnRect.Top + CloseBtnSize;
    CloseBtnRect.Left := CloseBtnRect.Right - CloseBtnSize;
    FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex] := CloseBtnRect;

    PageControl.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    PageControl.Canvas.TextOut(TabCaption.X, TabCaption.Y, PageControl.Pages[TabIndex].Caption);

    if not UseThemes then
    begin
      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE + DFCS_PUSHED
      else
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE;

      Windows.DrawFrameControl(PageControl.Canvas.Handle,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex], DFC_CAPTION, CloseBtnDrawState);
    end
    else
    begin
      Dec(FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex].Left);

      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonPushed)
      else
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonNormal);

      ThemeServices.DrawElement(PageControl.Canvas.Handle, CloseBtnDrawDetails,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex]);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1 do
    begin
      if PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[I], Point(X, Y)) then
      begin
        FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := I;
        FCloseButtonShowPushed := True;
        PageControl.Repaint;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  Inside: Boolean;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if (ssLeft in Shift) and (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex >= 0) then
  begin
    Inside := PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex], Point(X, Y));

    if FCloseButtonShowPushed <> Inside then
    begin
      FCloseButtonShowPushed := Inside;
      PageControl.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;
  FCloseButtonShowPushed := False;
  PageControl.Repaint;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if (Button = mbLeft) and (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex >= 0) then
  begin
    if PtInRect(FCloseButtonsRect[FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex], Point(X, Y)) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Button ' + IntToStr(FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex + 1) + ' pressed!');

      FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex := -1;
      PageControl.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Looks like:

[image: page control with buttons]

Comment: Looks very nice.  Screenshot is a nice touch! Unfortunately, it looks only suitable for Windows 2000 or non-themed XP?Vista/7.  Do you have a version that uses the theming API?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works well. So I select your code as the answer. But because of other featuers I need I decide to use a TJvTabBar from Jedi JVCL with a littel modified TJvTabBarXPPainter.

Comment: What is the InRange function? I guess it is a D2010 specific function which I don't have in D2009. Is there a similar function in D2009 avaialble?

Comment: It works fine on Delphi 2007, to use the function InRange, you must add the "Math" unit to the form's uses section.

Comment: Doesn't show the Page control tab images. Needs more work.

Answer (score 6):

It's often a good idea to implement this yourself, as the other answers have suggested.  Just in case you are already using [Raize Components](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp), though, this feature is supported "out of the box".  Just set `TRzPageControl.ShowCloseButtonOnActiveTab := true`, and handle the `OnClose` event.  The component takes care of placement for a variety of tab layouts/orientations/shapes/colors.

[just a happy customer]

Answer (score 4):

What I have done in the past is just put a TBitBtn with a graphic in the upper right hand corner of the TPageControl.  The trick i the parent of the TBitBtn is the same as the TPageControl, so it isn't actually on one of the tab sheets.  Then in the click even for that button:

```
PageControl1.ActivePage.Free;
```

When the current TTabControl is freed it notifies the TPageControl that owns it.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed a little this example:
- created class TCloseTabSheet
- this class has property OnClose: TNotifyEvent, which will be called if assigned
- if TabSheet of of TPageControl isn't that class then there is no close button
- if it is then Button showed. When you press close button it calls OnClose
- now you dont need to control the array FCloseButtonsRect, cause this Rects stored at TCloseTabSheet

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, Themes, Math, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type TCloseTabSheet=class(TTabSheet)
  private
  protected
    FCloseButtonRect: TRect;
    FOnClose: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure DoClose; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
property OnClose:TNotifyEvent read FOnClose write FOnClose;
end;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    PageControlCloseButton: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer;
      const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
      Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControlCloseButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
      Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure CloseTabeProc(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCloseButtonMouseDownTab: TCloseTabSheet;
    FCloseButtonShowPushed: Boolean;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TCloseTabSheet.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCloseButtonRect:=Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
end;

destructor TCloseTabSheet.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCloseTabSheet.DoClose;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnClose) then FOnClose(Self);
  Free;
end;

procedure TMainForm.CloseTabeProc(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('close');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
    NT:TCloseTabSheet;
begin
  PageControlCloseButton.TabWidth := 150;
  PageControlCloseButton.OwnerDraw := True;
  NT:=TCloseTabSheet.Create(PageControlCloseButton);
  NT.Caption:='TabSheet4';
  NT.PageControl:=PageControlCloseButton;
  NT.OnClose:=CloseTabeProc;

  FCloseButtonMouseDownTab := nil;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  CloseBtnSize: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabSheet:TCloseTabSheet;
  TabCaption: TPoint;
  CloseBtnRect: TRect;
  CloseBtnDrawState: Cardinal;
  CloseBtnDrawDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  PageControl := Control as TPageControl;
  TabCaption.Y := Rect.Top + 3;

  if Active then
  begin
    CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 4;
    CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
    TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 6;
  end
  else
  begin
    CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 3;
    CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
    TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 3;
  end;
  if PageControl.Pages[TabIndex] is TCloseTabSheet then
  begin
    TabSheet:=PageControl.Pages[TabIndex] as TCloseTabSheet;
    CloseBtnSize := 14;

    CloseBtnRect.Bottom := CloseBtnRect.Top + CloseBtnSize;
    CloseBtnRect.Left := CloseBtnRect.Right - CloseBtnSize;
    TabSheet.FCloseButtonRect := CloseBtnRect;

    PageControl.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    PageControl.Canvas.TextOut(TabCaption.X, TabCaption.Y,
            PageControl.Pages[TabIndex].Caption);

    if not ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
    begin
      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownTab = TabSheet) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE + DFCS_PUSHED
      else
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE;

      Windows.DrawFrameControl(PageControl.Canvas.Handle,
        TabSheet.FCloseButtonRect, DFC_CAPTION, CloseBtnDrawState);
    end
    else
    begin
      Dec(TabSheet.FCloseButtonRect.Left);

      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownTab = TabSheet) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonPushed)
      else
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonNormal);

      ThemeServices.DrawElement(PageControl.Canvas.Handle, CloseBtnDrawDetails,
                TabSheet.FCloseButtonRect);
    end;
  end else begin
    PageControl.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    PageControl.Canvas.TextOut(TabCaption.X, TabCaption.Y,
                 PageControl.Pages[TabIndex].Caption);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PageControlCloseButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabSheet:TCloseTabSheet;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    for I := 0 to PageControl.PageCount - 1 do
    begin
      if not (PageControl.Pages[i] is TCloseTabSheet) then Continue;
      TabSheet:=PageControl.Pages[i] as TCloseTabSheet;
      if PtInRect(TabSheet.FCloseButtonRect, Point(X, Y)) then
      begin
        FCloseButtonMouseDownTab := TabSheet;
        FCloseButtonShowPushed := True;
        PageControl.Repaint;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PageControlCloseButtonMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;
  FCloseButtonShowPushed := False;
  PageControl.Repaint;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PageControlCloseButtonMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  Inside: Boolean;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if (ssLeft in Shift) and Assigned(FCloseButtonMouseDownTab) then
  begin
    Inside := PtInRect(FCloseButtonMouseDownTab.FCloseButtonRect, Point(X, Y));

    if FCloseButtonShowPushed <> Inside then
    begin
      FCloseButtonShowPushed := Inside;
      PageControl.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PageControlCloseButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  PageControl: TPageControl;
begin
  PageControl := Sender as TPageControl;

  if (Button = mbLeft) and Assigned(FCloseButtonMouseDownTab) then
  begin
    if PtInRect(FCloseButtonMouseDownTab.FCloseButtonRect, Point(X, Y)) then
    begin
      FCloseButtonMouseDownTab.DoClose;
      FCloseButtonMouseDownTab := nil;
      PageControl.Repaint;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```