# Owner Drawn TPageControl OnMouse events fail to fire when docking a form as a tab

Tags: delphi, user-interface, tpagecontrol

Using the example provided here [How to implement a close button for a TTabsheet of a TPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201850/how-to-implement-a-close-button-for-a-ttabsheet-of-a-tpagecontrol) combined with setting a forms parent to a tab sheet with matching caption I was able to take my pagecontrol with forms attached as TTabSheet and add a close button and image from an image list much like you see on today's web browsers.

When I change

```
procedure TMainfrm.SOTest(Sender: TObject);
var
  ATab: TTabSheet;
  AForm: TMyForm;
begin
  { Tabbed }
  ATab:= TTabSheet.Create(MainPageControl);
  ATab.PageControl := MainPageControl;
  MainPageControl.ActivePage := ATab;
  AForm:= TMyForm.Create(ATab);
  AForm.Show;
  ATab.Caption := AForm.Caption;
end;
```

to

```
procedure TMainfrm.SOTest(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm: TMyForm;
begin
  AForm:= TMyForm.Create(Application);
  AForm.Show;
  AForm.DragKind := dkDock;
  AForm.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
  AForm.ManualDock(MainPageControl,MainPageControl,alClient);
  AForm.Caption := 'StackOverFlow';
end;
```

The OnMouse events do not pick up on any docked forms thus causing the close button to stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you're setting the `DockSite` property of the page control (though it is not mentioned in the question). When DockSite is set, a drag object is created when left button of the mouse is pressed and then the mouse is captured by this object (this is done to be able to automatically drag out the form). Thus it is this object that processes the mouse messages until the capture is released, which is done in a `WM_LBUTTONUP` case in `TDragObject.WndProc`.

<strike>Overriding WndProc, deriving a new class and putting a message handler etc. will not work, because the page control is not delivered any mouse messages while the mouse is captured by the drag object. Even using Application.OnMessage would be clumsy at best since Msg.hwnd would point to a different window each time the mouse is clicked.</strike>

What you can do, for instance, is in one way or another subclass the page control to be able to intercept `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, perform a test there and release the capture if the click is on a tab buton. A very dirty quick example based on the linked question:

```
type
  TPageControl = class(comctrls.TPageControl)
  private
    procedure WmLButtonDown(var Msg: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
  end;

  TMainfrm = class(TForm)
  ..

procedure TPageControl.WmLButtonDown(var Msg: TWMLButtonDown);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  inherited;                     // mouse will be captured here
  for I := 0 to Length(Mainfrm.FCloseButtonsRect) - 1 do
  begin
    if PtInRect(Mainfrm.FCloseButtonsRect[I], SmallPointToPoint(Msg.Pos)) then
    begin
      ReleaseCapture;            // and released here 
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you - this makes me understand the issue.