# close button of a tabsheet not supporting vcl styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles, tpagecontrol

I have used the code provided in this example [How to implement a close button for a TTabsheet of a TPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201850/how-to-implement-a-close-button-for-a-ttabsheet-of-a-tpagecontrol?) to draw a close button to each tabsheet of a pagecontrol and I have replaced ThemeServices with Style Services inside the code and when applying styles the close button doesn`t show and react in no way. Could anyone point me to a different path o solving this issue. thank you! this is the code of the OnDrawTab event:

```
  procedure TFormMain.PageControlCloseButtonDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
  CloseBtnSize: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabCaption: TPoint;
  CloseBtnRect: TRect;
  CloseBtnDrawState: Cardinal;
  CloseBtnDrawDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  PageControl := Control as TPageControl;

  if InRange(TabIndex, 0, Length(FCloseButtonsRect) - 1) then
  begin
    CloseBtnSize := 14;
    TabCaption.Y := Rect.Top + 3;

    if Active then
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 4;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 6;
    end
    else
    begin
      CloseBtnRect.Top := Rect.Top + 3;
      CloseBtnRect.Right := Rect.Right - 5;
      TabCaption.X := Rect.Left + 3;
    end;

    CloseBtnRect.Bottom := CloseBtnRect.Top + CloseBtnSize;
    CloseBtnRect.Left := CloseBtnRect.Right - CloseBtnSize;
    FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex] := CloseBtnRect;

    PageControl.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    PageControl.Canvas.TextOut(TabCaption.X, TabCaption.Y, PageControl.Pages[TabIndex].Caption);

    if not UseThemes then
    begin
      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE + DFCS_PUSHED
      else
        CloseBtnDrawState := DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE;

      Winapi.Windows.DrawFrameControl(PageControl.Canvas.Handle,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex], DFC_CAPTION, CloseBtnDrawState);
    end
    else
    begin
      Dec(FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex].Left);

      if (FCloseButtonMouseDownIndex = TabIndex) and FCloseButtonShowPushed then
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonPushed)
      else
        CloseBtnDrawDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twCloseButtonNormal);

      StyleServices.DrawElement(PageControl.Canvas.Handle, CloseBtnDrawDetails,
        FCloseButtonsRect[TabIndex]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's because VCL styles has its own `DrawTab` method. You have to create your own VCL style hook and draw those close buttons additionally there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using the vcl styles, you must write a  vcl style hook to draw a close button in the tab controls, take a look to the  [Vcl.Styles.ColorTabs](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.ColorTabs.pas) unit (introduced in these articles [Creating colorful tabsheets with the VCL Styles](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/creating-colorful-tabsheets-with-the-vcl-styles/), [Added border to TTabColorControlStyleHook](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/added-border-to-ttabcolorcontrolstylehook/)) to have an idea of what you need to write a style hook like this. Additional to the code to draw the button in the tabs you must handle the  WM_MOUSEMOVE and WM_LBUTTONUP messages (in the style hook) to change the state of the button (normal, hot) and detect a click in the close button.

If you have problems implementing the style hook let me know to post a full solution here.

**UPDATE**

I just wrote this simple style hook to add suport for a close button in the tabsheets.

```
uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

type
  TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose = class(TTabControlStyleHook)
  private
    FHotIndex       : Integer;
    FWidthModified  : Boolean;
    procedure WMMouseMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
    procedure WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMMouse); message WM_LBUTTONUP;
    function GetButtonCloseRect(Index: Integer):TRect;
  strict protected
    procedure DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseEnter; override;
    procedure MouseLeave; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AControl: TWinControl); override;
  end;

constructor TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.Create(AControl: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  FHotIndex:=-1;
  FWidthModified:=False;
end;

procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer);
var
  Details : TThemedElementDetails;
  ButtonR : TRect;
  FButtonState: TThemedWindow;
begin
  inherited;

  if (FHotIndex>=0) and (Index=FHotIndex) then
   FButtonState := twSmallCloseButtonHot
  else
  if Index = TabIndex then
   FButtonState := twSmallCloseButtonNormal
  else
   FButtonState := twSmallCloseButtonDisabled;

  Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(FButtonState);

  ButtonR:= GetButtonCloseRect(Index);
  if ButtonR.Bottom - ButtonR.Top > 0 then
   StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, ButtonR);
end;

procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMMouse);
Var
  LPoint : TPoint;
  LIndex : Integer;
begin
  LPoint:=Message.Pos;
  for LIndex := 0 to TabCount-1 do
   if PtInRect(GetButtonCloseRect(LIndex), LPoint) then
   begin
      if Control is TPageControl then
      begin
        TPageControl(Control).Pages[LIndex].Parent:=nil;
        TPageControl(Control).Pages[LIndex].Free;
      end;
      break;
   end;
end;

procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.WMMouseMove(var Message: TMessage);
Var
  LPoint : TPoint;
  LIndex : Integer;
  LHotIndex : Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  LHotIndex:=-1;
  LPoint:=TWMMouseMove(Message).Pos;
  for LIndex := 0 to TabCount-1 do
   if PtInRect(GetButtonCloseRect(LIndex), LPoint) then
   begin
      LHotIndex:=LIndex;
      break;
   end;

   if (FHotIndex<>LHotIndex) then
   begin
     FHotIndex:=LHotIndex;
     Invalidate;
   end;
end;

function TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.GetButtonCloseRect(Index: Integer): TRect;
var
  FButtonState: TThemedWindow;
  Details : TThemedElementDetails;
  R, ButtonR : TRect;
begin
  R := TabRect[Index];
  if R.Left < 0 then Exit;

  if TabPosition in [tpTop, tpBottom] then
  begin
    if Index = TabIndex then
      InflateRect(R, 0, 2);
  end
  else
  if Index = TabIndex then
    Dec(R.Left, 2)
  else
    Dec(R.Right, 2);

  Result := R;
  FButtonState := twSmallCloseButtonNormal;

  Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(FButtonState);
  if not StyleServices.GetElementContentRect(0, Details, Result, ButtonR) then
    ButtonR := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

  Result.Left :=Result.Right - (ButtonR.Width) - 5;
  Result.Width:=ButtonR.Width;
end;

procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.MouseEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  FHotIndex := -1;
end;

procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.MouseLeave;
begin
  inherited;
  if FHotIndex >= 0 then
  begin
    FHotIndex := -1;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

Register in this way

```
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl, TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TTabControl, TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);
```

And this is a demo

[image]

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, i have tried to implement a custom style hook after TLama sugested me to do so, but i am overwhelmed with this stuff; the thing with vcl styles is that i can't find  much documentation, excepting your blog. I have tried a couple of your examples, but i can't handle on my own; I need some material also about handling windows messages.I will try to have a look again on google and after a few time of reading i will give it another try.Thanks for the advices guys!

Comment: Worked for me, although they work entirely different than your demo. First of all, they overlap the label for me. Second of all, they only show when hovering over the tab. Third of all, they show really, really small. Using XE7 with Silver style. Are those differences controlled by the styles?

Comment: Actually they do show flat by default, couldn't see them because they're overlapping the text. I Have to hover over the tiny `x` to make the full button visible. Also had to add 5 spaces to the end of each caption.  Uggg :-) http://i.imgbox.com/YHlCTt13.png

Comment: @JerryDodge, This is a very basic implementation, you can resolve the issue recalculating the width of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been working on this example, and i got it working on the Metro UI on delphi XE6.

My workaround for getting the correct distance between the Tab name and the button was to modify this line

```
Result.Left := Result.Right - (ButtonR.Width);
//it was   Result.Left := Result.Right - (ButtonR.Width) -5;
```

And setting a bigger TabWith on the PageController properties.

Also ,remind that the "Register" lines, goes on the Initialization class right before the end of the unit.

```
 //...all the code of the unit

Initialization

TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl,
  TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);
TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TTabControl,
  TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);

end.//final unit "end" =D
```