# How to apply a vcl style hook to a particular component of a form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using the vcl style hook of the answer to this question [`close button of a tabsheet not supporting vcl styles`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531153/close-button-of-a-tabsheet-not-supporting-vcl-styles) and is working fine, but the close button is draw in all the TPageControl components of my app.

[image]

And I want add this option (draw the close button) to only a particular form. The question is : how I can apply this hook or any vcl style hook just  to the TPageControl of a specific form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a interposer class for the TPageControl component

check this sample

```
type
  TPageControl = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl);
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    ...
    ...
```

And then register the vcl style hook in the same unit where the interposer class is located

```
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TPageControl, TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);
```

Or using a full qualified type name

```
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(Unit1.TPageControl, TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose);
```